# Filter using drop down list and text box in angular 4

Tags: html, angular

I am doing filtering in angular 4. For filtering I am using text box and drop down list. In the table I am having fields invoice number, client name, status, amount. I am filtering all the status (status possible are paid, unpaid, open etc) in the drop down list. And all the other fields like invoice number, client name and amount are filtering using the text box. It is filtering separately now. What I want now is to combine both. That is after filtering based on drop down list, the status is selected, the result is again filtered using the text box and vice versa, if the text box filtering is also needed for the first result

Component.ts Code:

```
status = ['All', 'Unpaid and sent', 'Unpaid with due date', 'Paid', 'Open', 'Overdue'];
 _listFilter: string;
    get listFilter(): string {
        return this._listFilter;
    }
    set listFilter(value: string) {
        this._listFilter = value;
        this.filteredInvoice = this.listFilter ? this.performFilter(this.listFilter) : this.invo;
    }
    filteredInvoice: IInvoice[];
    invo: IInvoice[] = [];
 onOptionsSelected() {
        /
        console.log(this.selected);

        let today: Date = new Date();
        switch (this.selected) {
            case "All":
                this.invo = this.route.snapshot.data['invoices'];
                break;

       case "Paid":
                this.filteredInvoice = this.invo.filter(invoice => invoice.status == "Paid" );
                break;
            case "Unpaid and sent":
                this.filteredInvoice = this.invo.filter(invoice => invoice.status == "Sent");
                break;

            case "Unpaid within due date":
                this.filteredInvoice = this.invo.filter(invoice => invoice.status == "Sent" && today <= invoice.dateDue);
                break;
            case "Overdue":
                this.filteredInvoice = this.invo.filter(invoice => invoice.status == "Sent" && today > invoice.dateDue);
                break;

        }

    }





    performFilter(filterBy: any): IInvoice[] {
       filterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
        return this.invo.filter((inv: IInvoice) =>
           (inv.clientName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1) || (inv.invoiceNumber.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1)
            ||  (inv.dateCreated.toString().toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1)
            || (inv.dateDue.toString().toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1) || (inv.grandTotal.toString().toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1));




    }


   HTML Code:

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">Filter by:</div>

    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="listFilter" name="clientName" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">




</div>

<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
        <h3>Filtered by: {{listFilter}} </h3>
    </div>
</div>
<select [(ngModel)]="selected" name="status" placeholder="select" (ngModelChange)="onOptionsSelected($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let sta of status" [ngValue]="sta">{{sta}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: do you have a filter button?

Comment: No. It is filtering based on what written in text box or selected on drop down list

Comment: inorder to combine both you need a common action